# Specify default substitution font when converting pdf to image using imagemagick and font is missing

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am using [Spatie/pdfToImage](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image) that builds on ghost script and imagemagick to on my server:

1. Take a multiple page pdf from an email using mailgun routing.
2. Save the pdf in folder /docs_pdf like file.pdf
3. Use a foreach to loop through each page and save each page as a png to /docs like file_#.png

locally where I use laravel -> valet everything works fine.

On my server using digital ocean through laravel forge the language in a multipaged pdf that is in swedish transforms from normal swedish to a bunch of random letters and signs.

The left is correct (yes, its true. Its Swedish) and the right is wrong:
[image]

Someone suggested to me that this is probably a matter of the font missing on the server. The fonts used in the pdf:

```
<</StemV 68/FontName/PSQHMO+FoundrySans-Normal/FontFile2 216 0 R/FontStretch/Normal/FontWeight 400/Flags 32/Descent -240/FontBBox[-40 -240 960 916]/Ascent 916/FontFamily(FoundrySans-Normal)/CapHeight 667/XHeight 465/Type/FontDescriptor/ItalicAngle 0>>
<</StemV 100/FontName/MLHPWU+FoundrySans-Medium/FontFile2 217 0 R/FontStretch/Normal/FontWeight 400/Flags 32/Descent -241/FontBBox[-42 -241 1008 916]/Ascent 916/FontFamily(FoundrySans-Medium)/CapHeight 667/XHeight 470/Type/FontDescriptor/ItalicAngle 0>>
<</StemV 68/FontName/SUEECI+FoundrySans-Normal/FontFile2 218 0 R/FontStretch/Normal/FontWeight 400/Flags 4/Descent -240/FontBBox[-40 -240 960 916]/Ascent 916/FontFamily(FoundrySans-Normal)/CapHeight 667/XHeight 465/Type/FontDescriptor/ItalicAngle 0>>
<</StemV 48/FontName/KIDDUY+FoundrySans-Light/FontFile2 9 0 R/FontStretch/Normal/FontWeight 400/Flags 32/Descent -248/FontBBox[-28 -248 978 924]/Ascent 924/FontFamily(FoundrySans-Light)/CapHeight 667/XHeight 458/Type/FontDescriptor/ItalicAngle 0>>
```

Here is configuration of fonts in imagemagick and ghostscript:
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php

how can this be solved?

Update:

I have now made a clean install on a new server.

Installed Imagick and spatie/pdfToImage

As suggested by KenS I ran

> gs -sDEVICE=png16m -o out%d.png

terminal output

```
forge@Server:~/app/storage/app/public/files$ gs -sDEVICE=png16m -o test_out%d.png file.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 9.22 (2017-10-04)
Copyright (C) 2017 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 2.
Page 1
Page 2
```

the document rendered the same = wrong.

I am at a complete loss.. Don't know what next step might be..

Update2:

I also run the convert imagemagick commando and the img rendered the same way also.

So even if I do it with ghostscript solo, imagemagick or spatie/pdfToImage it gives me the same output

Comment: It would be more helpful to see the actual PDF, rather than the configuration files (and you don't seem to have configured Ghostscript at all). Almost certainly you don't want to alter the **default** font at all, you want to specify a substitute for a particular missing font. The correct way to resolve this, of course, is to embed all fonts in the PDF file, then it will work everywhere. If you don't then it will only work where the specific font being used is available, and the default encoding of the font matches whatever encoding the PDF file uses <continued>.....

Comment: If you make the PDF file available, and can tell me which version of Ghostscript you are using, and the command line being used to start Ghostscript, I'll look at it.

Comment: @KenS thanks, this with ghostScript is new territory for me. I have a web app that handles PDFs from a lot of different origins. This is the one causing trouble right now: https://ufile.io/6o8yj - I assume there might be issues with future PDFs even if this specific one gets fixed? Hence the thoughts of some kind of catching of all troublesome fonts.

Comment: @KenS also this: GPL Ghostscript 9.25 (2018-09-13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. I want to first give kudos to KenS that really helped me, and without him it would not have worked.

This is what I did:

1 - I removed Ghostscript:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ghostscript
```

then

```
wget https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs925/ghostscript-9.25.tar.gz

tar xvf ghostscript-9.25.tar.gz
```

Enter the unpacked folder and do

```
./configure

make

make install
```

then

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/bin/gs
```

On top of the above I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:glasen/freetype2
```

and then:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install freetype2-demos
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the current version of Ghostscript (9.25) renders this acceptably for me; that is the text appears to be correct. All the fonts are embedded, so there **shouldn't** be any problems.

And this means that even if you did replace the default font substitution, it wouldn't help, because Ghostscript shouldn't be using the default font, it will be using the fonts embedded in the PDF file.

Without knowing what version of Ghostscript you are using (I see from a later comment that  its 9.25), or the command line that is used to start it, I can't really do a like-for-like comparison. Its hard for me to see how you could be getting such a different result though. That looks like Ghostscript has failed to find the embedded fonts.

Its possible that whatever package you are using has done something 'unfortunate'. The various package maintainers on Linux add their own patches, and sometimes modify the way that Ghostscript is built. Possibly that has broken something.

If you are able to build Ghostscript yourself you could try cloning our Git repository and doing that. You could also try downloading the Linux binaries off our website. They won't work with every Linux distribution (different ABI) but you can try, you might be lucky.

You could also try running Ghostscript directly on the PDF file. Something like:

> gs -sDEVICE=png16m -o out%d.png

should produce 2 PNG files, out1.png and out2.png. It will also produce a bunch of stuff on the terminal. That back channel output is valuable information for me so if you can reproduce the problem, I'd like to see that too.

One last thought; its possible to have more than one version of Ghostscript installed simultaneously, its possible that your current setup is using an old version of Ghostscript.

I can't help you with ImageMagick or Spatie, but if you can debug those to the point where you can reproduce the problem with a plain Ghostscript command line then I can look further at it.

Comment: GPL Ghostscript 9.22 (2017-10-04)
Copyright (C) 2017 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 2.
Page 1
Page 2

Comment: I ran the command you suggested. I see there that it is using Ghostscript 9.22. the idiot that I am I checked yesterday locally where it works thats where I have 9.25......... so I will start with updating gs. I get back with the outcome

Comment: I tried 9.22 here, and it also works, so I'm at something of a loss, I'll wait for your results.....

Comment: ok, hmm. I can't seem to figure out how to force update to 9.25 on the server as my ubuntu provides for 9.22... I will try to privision a new server with clean install of everything and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I made a clean install. Issue persists... "That back channel output is valuable information" how can I grab that?

Comment: So even if I do it with ghostscript solo, imagemagick or spatie/pdfToImage it gives me the same output

Comment: The back channel output is sent to stdout, so normally it will appear in the terminal window, you can of course redirect it with '>' to a file. Did you say above that it works locally ? If so then there is something different between your two setups, I can't tell you what that would be, I can't reproduce your problem at all.

Comment: it works locally. perfect. It is on the server..... Locally I have 9.25. I just added the terminal output to the update in the question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: OK so you seem to be running 9.22. While I can't reproduce your problem with that version, it does seem likely (given that your local 9.25 doesn't have a problem) that you need to upgrade the version on your server. Ah, one thing that did just occur to me; the various distro maintainers have a penchant for building Ghostscript so that it uses system shared libraries. Its possible that you need to update the version of FreeType on your system, or build Ghostscript with the FreeType source that we ship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180452/discussion-between-brainmaniac-and-kens).

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have time to use the chat in SO.